# Possible cause java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, sql, winapi, postgresql

I am trying to execute 'VACUUM VERBOSE' command through java.
Here is my code

```
public void executeCommand()
{
    String cmd1= "cmd.exe /c start";
    String location="C:\\PROGRA~1\\PostgreSQL\\8.3\\bin\\";
    String postgresCommand="psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres";
    String autoVaccum="-c \"vacuum verbose\"";
    String []actualCmd={cmd1,location,postgresCommand,autoVaccum};

    Process process=null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(actualCmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyTest test= new MyTest();
    test.executeCommand();

}
```

But I am getting following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe /c start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at MyTest.executeCommand(MyTest.java:36)
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

When I directly type above strings directly in Start-> Run window its executes sucessfully
Eg.
cmd.exe /C start  C:\PROGRA~1/PostgreSQL/8.3/bin/psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -c "vacuum verbose"

Can anybody know what exactly going wrong in above program?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to call exec().  The on you're using, which takes String[] as an argument, expects each token to be in a different part of the array.  So the call for

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start executable arg1 arg2");
```

when called with an array instead of one string is called as

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c","start","executable","arg1","arg2");    
BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter outWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
```

exec() returns a Process object, that you then can grab the output of with getInputStream().  This is actually the output from the process, it's input to your java code.  You can then read it the same as any other stream and display it to the user as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks Thomas,
I did little modification in my code. Instead of String array used single string and now problem is resolved 

 String actualCmd=cmd1 + location + postgresCommand + autoVaccum;

But still this program is not opening command line window which shows what operations are performed by "VACUUM VERBOSE" command

But When I execute other command using this program it opens command line window 
Eg. String cmd1= "cmd.exe /c start dir";

Basically I wanted to show output of 'vacuum command' to user

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `cmd.exe /c start` as a single argument, so it looks for a file called exactly `cmd.exe /c start` and fails.

Instead, split `cmd1` into two strings: `cmd.exe` and `/c start`